# jqGrid - columns padding issue in google chrome when use RTL

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jqgrid, right-to-left

I use jqGrid plugin and I set `direction: "rtl"` in the options. I need to have horizontal scroll bar, because I have too many columns. My problem is columns body height not synchronized with columns header height in google chrome when I have horizontal scroll bar. I post two pictures and hope these pictures can explain my problem. Thanks in advance.

Grid screenshot when there is no horizontal scroll bar:
[image]
Every things is ok here.

And here is screenshot when there is horizontal scrollbar:
[image]

Note that this is just example and in my real application I have more than 20 columns in the grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm, that jqGrid have some problems with column alignment in case of usage `direction: "rtl"`. If you use `height: "auto"` option then I would recommend you to use additional CSS rule

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-hbox-rtl { padding-left: 0 }
```

and include additionally include the line

```js
this.grid.hDiv.scrollLeft = this.grid.bDiv.scrollLeft;
```

inside of `loadComplete` and `resizeStop`.

The problem is that `padding-left: 0` can be used not in all situations. I described the approach how the problem could be solved in my posts to [the issue](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/issues/612).

I'm developing now new **free version** of jqGrid, which you can download from [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). It contains fixes of to the problem which you described. I recommend you to try the version. It contains many bug fixes and the features like new `iconSet: "fontAwesome"` option which improves the look of jqGrid. See some demos at the end of [the page](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). If you would describe me any bugs (in [the issues](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues) part, or on the stackoveflow) or RTL specific problems (or suggestions to improve RTL look) I would try to improve RTL support in jqGrid.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. your solutions always help me to improve my application. I use jqgird for a while and use lots of your solutions about jqgrid issues in stack :) So many thanks for your attention.

Comment: Is there any fixes about virtual scrolling problem in this new jqgrid version?

Comment: @hamed: No. Two parts of jqGrid need be changes much more as other: virtual scrolling and fixed columns. Probably one will have to rewrite many parts (or the whole) of the current implementation. I plan to publish the first my version of jqGrid this month. I'll came back to virtual scrolling and fixed columns in the next version only. Do you have some suggestions or examples, what is bad implemented in jqGrid from RTL point of view? For example dialog resizer in on the wrong place, the order of buttons and so on. I could fix the problems in my version of jqGrid (still in the month).

Comment: I added .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-hbox-rtl { padding-left: 0 } and  this.grid.hDiv.scrollLeft = this.grid.bDiv.scrollLeft; in my jqgrid code. The problem solved in google chrome, but same problem created in firefox! Before change, firefox was ok and chrome had problem, But now, chrome is ok and firefox has problem! How can I fix it? Please help me. Thank you @Oleg

Comment: @hamed: Do you have the demo which reproduces the problem? Could you post me the URL? Do you try the same code with [my current version of jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/groupingRtl1.htm) for example?

Comment: Thank you @Oleg. I tested it with your new version, but I didn't see any change. If the grid hasn't horizontal scroll bar, everything is ok, but my grid has horizontal scroll bar. And your demo has not horizontal scroll bar and so it couldn't help me. Unfortunately I haven't any domain or blog for uploading my code :( Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @hamed: You are welcome! I included `width` option in jqGrid on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/groupingRtl1.htm) and still can't see any problem in Firefox. The results on Firefox looks like on the [the following animated gif](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/resizing.gif). You can create the demo using [jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for example. You can modify [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ygqwy0h6/) which uses my modified jqGrid or [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/t9L0b2sy/) which uses jqGrid 4.6.

Comment: Thank you for attention. I tested your demo and every thing was ok. I created a fiddle with your new jqgrid version and [this is the link](http://jsfiddle.net/xbLjre6m/) . this works without problem in firefox, but has problem in google chrome.

Comment: @hamed: You are welcome! Sorry, but what problem exactly exist in Google Chrome with the jsfiddle demo? I look at http://jsfiddle.net/xbLjre6m/, but I don't see any problems. Could you describe exactly test case and the problem itself: what steps should be done to reproduce the problem. Which zoom you use? What are expected results and what you see. You can write new issue in https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues. Using drag&drop you can include pictures. You can use [LICEcap](https://github.com/lepht/licecap) tool to create animated gif with the steps to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I had tested that fiddle in company, and now when I test in my home, I don't see any problems. I think the problem is related to google chrome version. My google chrome version at company is 27 and at home is 38.

Comment: @hamed: If you will do find any problem later, just let me known. You can write me about some other suggestions to improve visibility of jqGrid for RTL languages.